# Will Game of Thrones end like A Song of Ice and Fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

The *Game of Thrones* show has deviated from the *A Song of Ice and Fire* books and has gone beyond where the books left off while the author is still writing them.

Has there been any indication that Game of Thrones will have the same ending that George R.R. Martin planned for his books? Or could the books have a completely different ending that the show (like the Night King winning)?

I believe that Martin (like many writers) had the idea for the overall story and the (possibly/hopefully crazy twist) awesome ending since he originally conceived it. So even though he's behind the show in writing, he still had an ending planned that everything has been building up to. Is the TV show going to use the same ending that Martin had planned all along or have they created their own ending to the story?

Obviously we won't know for sure until the books are finished (i.e. <s>never</s> someday) but I was hoping that either HBO or Martin has commented about this.

Maybe Martin will just have Dean Allen Foster "finish" the last ones for him based on the scripts.

Comment: Relevant: [How much creative independence are the Show runners accorded in Game of Thrones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/180825/54887). We simply don't know. GRRM is known to dump hundreds of pages in the trashbin just because he doesn't like the path they take his characters on (e.g. Tyrion's arc in ADWD and TWOW). We also know GRRM changed his original intended ending with Arya and Jon hooking up at the Wall. Since GRRM isn't quite involved in the show, D&D have full independence and GRRM changes stuff as he likes, its fairly likely that Books will have a much better ending than show

Comment: Voted to leave open. We might not know, but "has there been a word on that from the authors/showrunners/officials" isn't opinion-based.

Comment: As far as I know the ending of A Song of Ice and Fire is unwritten at the moment, and although GRRM may have told the show runners of Game of Thrones how he plans to end the novel series, they are not obligated to copy GRRM's ending and GRRM can still change his mind about his ending.  And GRRM might possibly decide to change his ending to make it less like the show's ending, so people don't think he was stuck and simply copied the show. Thus there seems only a small probability that the two endings will be very similar and if they are it might be merely by coincidence.

Comment: @Aegon - how is this question a DUPLICATE of a question that was asked three weeks later?

Comment: @HannoverFist I spotted the newer question first and answered there instead of here. :[ Since the answers are the same for both, it becomes a dupe in my understanding. You can of course always take it to meta or edit and push it to the queue. [See this meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4744/should-we-always-close-the-newer-question-as-the-duplicate) if it helps.

Comment: @Aegon: This is silly rule-thumping. If anything then, you would need then to delete your answer in the newer question, and repost it here in the older one.

Comment: @HannoverFist it was less of a duplicate before admins edited my question.  I specifically asked if, *now that the show is over*, GRRM has the option to end it in a different manner than the show, or if he was locked in by his contract with HBO to resolve the books in a manner consistent with the show.  This question, when originally posted, asked about the intention of future works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent video by Preston Jacobs goes into this exact question. (About 2:50 minutes in)

George goes back and forth on if the endings are the same or not and is never giving a consistent answer. Basically it comes down to you're asking if a normal man, with plenty of mistakes, knows for sure if an unfinished book series is going to end the same as an unfinished TV show written by someone else. I doubt that George himself knows exactly how the books will end, and I very much doubt that he has any input or information on how the show is ending.